# Adding v7 AppCompat Library to Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I properly add v7 AppCompat library to Android Studio? The catch is that it is a non-gradle project. I have to share the project with an Eclipse user.

I have tried adding the appcompat folder as a module, then adding the jar file inside as a library. After adding the jar as a library, I can access the ActionBarActivity class, so I know it at least somewhat worked. However when extending ActionBarActivity instead of Activity, I get a NoClassDefFoundError for android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable upon the onCreate super being called.

Comment: There is glitche to add an external library to android studio

Comment: Well I successfully added google play services by adding it with the same procedure I mentioned above. Do you have a source?

Comment: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable this comes because u have 2 android v4 libraray. First remove the library from the appcompact libs

Comment: I have removed the v4 library from appcompat, but still get the exact same error. I believe extra v4 is not the problem.

Comment: no an extra v4 is a problem because the sha-1 for ur project and in the appcompact will be a mismatch so it will give u an isue